# Java Spring initialize, call a method on startup

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to java spring framework, and I am trying to call a method or initialize a method on startup so when the application start, I will be able to see my data from the database on my jsp page. I have try @EventListener, @PostConstruct but nothing is working for me.

> **This is my WebConfigura class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.store.spring")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    lookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/product_db");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver resolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling (DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor());
}
}
```

> **This is Web Application Initializer class**

```
@Component
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(WebConfiguration.class);
    // Add context.setCongiglocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    registration.addMapping("/");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    ContextLoaderListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener(context);
    servletContext.addListener(listener);
}
}
```

> **This is the controller class**

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index(Model model) {
    List<Product> listProduct = productService.getPrducts();
    model.addAttribute("listProduct", listProduct);

    return "index";
}

// Request mapping using SQL tag
@RequestMapping("/location")
public String addLocation(Model model) {
    List<Product> listProduct = productService.getPrducts();
    model.addAttribute("listProduct", listProduct);

    return "location";
}

@RequestMapping("/entry")
public String entry() {
    return "Entry";
}

@RequestMapping("/aboutUs")
public String aboutUS() {return "AboutUs";}

@RequestMapping("/deal")
public String deal() {
    return "Deal";
}

@RequestMapping("/listProduct")
public String listOrganizationService(Model model) {
    List<Product> listProduct = productService.getPrducts();
    model.addAttribute("listProduct", listProduct);

    return "ListOrganizations";
}
}
```

> **This is the header interceptor class**

```
public class HeaderInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    request.setAttribute("title", "We hope you have a scary and fun filled halloween");
    String location = request.getParameter("locationName");
    if (location != null) {
        request.setAttribute("locationName", location);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

> **This is the method I want to initialize or call on start up. Or at least 
>   some thing close to this**

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index(Model model) {
List<Product> listProduct = productService.getPrducts();
model.addAttribute("listProduct", listProduct);

return "index";
}
```

> **I am using index.jsp to call the listProduct to print my data out. Notice that index.jsp is the first jsp that call when  the application start. And I want it to ab able to automatic print those data out**

```
<div class="main-container" style="text-align: center">
<c:forEach var="row" items="${listProduct}">
    <div class="detail">
        <td>ID: <c:out value="${row.id}"></c:out></td>
        <br/>
        <td>Name: <c:out value="${row.productName}"></c:out></td>
        <br/>
        <td>Quantity: <c:out value="${row.quantity}"></c:out></td>
        <br/>
        <td>Price: <c:out value="${row.price}"></c:out></td>
        <br/>
        <td><div class="few-line"><c:out value="${row.description}"></c:out></div></td>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I hope someone could help me out.

> **For Example I had this code inside my WebInitializer class, and when I run it I got an error message**

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void contextRefreshedEvent(Model model) {
    List<Product> productList = productService.getPrducts();
    model.addAttribute("productList", productList)
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256)
>       ... 56 more 
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start.
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context []
>   startup failed due to previous errors
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose
>   Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 13 10:43:51
>   EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>
> **These are my plug and dependencies for my jar**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your problem.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: "nothing is working for me." - what does this look like?

Answer (score 0):

> Java Spring initialize, call a method on startup

You can annotate a Spring bean's method with `@PostConstruct` to have Spring call it after it gets constructed.  You can also annotate a method with `@Autowired` to have Spring call it during the construction of that bean. We typically use one of those to call a method on startup, for example to load data from a database into cache.